# How can I send an int from a Task in JavaFx?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I´m trying to send an int from a `Task` but the method `updateMessage` only allows a `String`. I´ve tried to convert `.toString()` but the IDE sends error "Cannot resolve symbol".

Is there any way to do it? Why can´t I use `.toString()` inside a `Task`?

```
         bkgTimer = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        int count = 0;
                        while (play){
                            count++;
                            updateMessage(count.toString());//Cannot resolve symbol
                            if (isCancelled()) {
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        bkgTimer.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
               chronoLabel.textProperty().unbind();
            }
        });
        chronoLabel.textProperty().bind(bkgTimer.messageProperty());
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error has nothing to do with the fact that you are inside a `Task`. The issue is that you cannot call a method from a primitive type, such as `int`, `double`, `boolean`, etc. Only reference types (i.e. objects) have methods, and classes can define static methods.

So instead, use the static [`toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) method in the `Integer` class:

```
updateMessage(Integer.toString(count));
```

Comment: Couldn´t see the tree for the forest... Thank you!